# Cpu locked when using multiprocessing with python

Tags: python, join, multiprocessing, cpu-usage

My code:

```
def create_rods(folder="./", kappas=10, allowed_kappa_error=.3,
                radius_correction_ratio=0.1):
    """
    Create one rod for each rod_data and for each file
    returns [RodGroup1, RodGroup2, ...]
    """
    names, files = import_files(folder=folder)
    if len(files) == 0:
        print "No files to import."
        raise ValueError
    states = [None for dummy_ in range(len(files))]
    processes = []
    states_queue = mp.Queue()
    for index in range(len(files)):
        process = mp.Process(target=create_rods_process,
                        args=(kappas, allowed_kappa_error,
                        radius_correction_ratio, names,
                        files, index, states_queue))
        processes.append(process)
    run_processes(processes)        #This part seem to take a lot of time.
    try:
        while True:
            [index, state] = states_queue.get(False)
            states[index] = state
    except Queue.Empty:
        pass    
    return names, states

def create_rods_process(kappas, allowed_kappa_error,
                    radius_correction_ratio, names,
                    files, index, states_queue):
    """
    Process of method.
    """
    state = SystemState(kappas, allowed_kappa_error,
                radius_correction_ratio, names[index])
    data = import_data(files[index])
    for dataline in data:
        parameters = tuple(dataline)
        new_rod = Rod(parameters)
        state.put_rod(new_rod)
    state.check_rods()
    states_queue.put([index, state])

def run_processes(processes, time_out=None):
    """
        Runs all processes using all cores.
    """
    running = []
    cpus = mp.cpu_count()
    try:
        while True:
        #for cpu in range(cpus):
            next_process = processes.pop()
            running.append(next_process)
            next_process.start()
    except IndexError:
        pass
    if not time_out:
        try:
            while True:
                for process in running:
                    if not process.is_alive():
                        running.remove(process)
        except TypeError:
            pass
    else:
        for process in running:
            process.join(time_out)
```

I expect processes to end but I get a process stucked. I don't know if there is a problem with run_processes() method or with create_rods() method. With join cpus are freed, but program doesn't go on.

Comment: I get futex_wait_queue_me for all processes but one, who shows a 0 in that column and a 100% cpu use.

Comment: I have tried my run_processes function with a f(x)=x**2 function and gets blocked also, so it seems to be a run_processes error.

Comment: I changed the try, except with a if not len(running): break, and i stiil have the problem, but with f(x)=x**2 everything works as expected.

Comment: The problem has to do with Queue and how it's filled/emptied. I suppose I have an error with queue put timeout. I don't wanna loose what i put in the queue, but I don't know why take it so long. When running without multiprocessing, it takes a logical amount of time. So, how do i have to use the queue? does it has a max_size that forbids me to put data in? Should I use another structure?

Comment: Please fix the formatting and make the code more readable if you want help.

Comment: Sorry for indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Python's [multiprocessing guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#all-start-methods).

> Joining processes that use queues
>
> Bear in mind that a process that has put items in a queue will wait before terminating until all the buffered items are fed by the “feeder” thread to the underlying pipe. (The child process can call the Queue.cancel_join_thread method of the queue to avoid this behaviour.)
>
> This means that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed before the process is joined. Otherwise you cannot be sure that processes which have put items on the queue will terminate. Remember also that non-daemonic processes will be joined automatically.

Joining processes before draining their Queues results in a deadlock. You need to be sure the queues are emptied before joining the processes.